# Heroku and Django 1.7 - code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy a django app on heroku for the first time and I am stuck on the same problem for a loooooong time : 
Everytime I do

```
heroku open
```

My app crashes and heroku logs says :

```
2015-03-27T13:40:21.519526+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v12 created by lucasberbesson@gmail.com
2015-03-27T13:40:21.672768+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed
to starting
2015-03-27T13:40:26.353481+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command 
`: gunicorn lafusee.wsgi --log-file -`
2015-03-27T13:40:28.926043+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-03-27T13:40:28.916906+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2015-03-27T13:40:50.161396+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by lucasberbesson@gmail.com
2015-03-27T13:43:01.661152+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/" host=murmuring-beach-3485.herokuapp.com 
request_id=997024d3-f75e-4e54-80a6-47384b4d4700 fwd="83.202.1.92" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-03-27T13:43:02.345073+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=murmuring-beach-
3485.herokuapp.com request_id=7516bea9-fc53-4db2-af0a-2acc479db77d 
fwd="83.202.1.92" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

My Procfile ( wsgi.py in lafusee app):

```
web : gunicorn lafusee.wsgi --log-file -
```

How can I get a more descriptive error message from heroku to try to debug my project ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if `requirements.txt` contains `gunicron`.

Also try to set Procfile as:
`web : gunicorn lafusee.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT`